# Why is my div not in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

My result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTMUw.png
My style.css

```
body {
background: url("img/bgs.png") repeat #cccccc;
color: #000000;
}


main {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

My index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Progress</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css3-progress-bar.css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>


<div id="main">
<p><b>215/160 LBS.</b></p>
<div class="bar_mortice rounded green_mortice">
      <div class="progress rounded green" style="width: 05%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Why is the text not centering? Also, the progress bar was not centering until I added the

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

I tried that under main but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the css, you need to use `#main` instead of just `main`.

Also, you'll want to give it some width, otherwise it may take up the entire width. Try this:

```
#main {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `div#main` is overkill, `#main` is enough. Also `margin: auto` for a neater code

Comment: @ThanhTrung I agree with you on `div`, but I'm a sucker for explicitly marking each side of margin and padding. The explicitness is worth the verbosity.

Comment: @speedplane I tried with margin: 0 50px; but the text on top of the bar would be off. Not dead on center. I added the margin-left/right to auto again and it's right back on the left. why?

Comment: You'll need to position the progress bar in the middle of `main`. Try adding css like this: `#main .progress { margin: auto; }`